# Applescript: set folder as current folder

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to move a file to the current folder in Finder, with Applescript. The end result would be being in a specific folder in the Finder, hitting a shortcut on the keyboard, and having the file moved from the Downloads folder to the current folder.

I'm struggling to find a way to refer to the current folder, and to test this out in Applescript. Does anyone have any idea on the subject?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Finder has no notion of a "current folder". The folder that the user might be said to be "in" is the folder represented by the Finder's first *window*. You can experiment by saying:

```
tell application "Finder"
    activate
    try
        get folder of window 1
    end try
end tell
```

Comment: What about `insertion location`?

Comment: @Mockman That's kind of brilliant; it gives the same result but it has the advantage that it works even if no window is open.

Comment: @Mockman: could you share how you'd use the "insertion location" into a code? Thanks!

Comment: Exactly as I did. Instead of `get folder of window 1` you say `get insertion location`.

Comment: @Gabriel It is a property of the Finder application (so take a look in the Finder dictionary). As matt suggests, you can `get insertion location`. I would play around with it, outside of a 'try' statement so that you can see what it returns. You can coerce it into an alias or file as well, e.g. `insertion location as alias` or `… as text`.

Comment: Correct, and that's true for `get folder...` as well: depending on how you want to use it, you can transform this reference.